# XML data is not showing up when assigned to asp:Literal using ReadOuterXml()

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlreader

XML data is not showing up on my asp.net webpage, when I assign it to an `<asp:Literal>` even though when in debug mode, my string variable `xmlText` is storing all of my XML data.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
using (connection)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
    cmd.CommandText = "GenerateXMLReport";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();

    XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
    if (reader.Read())
        while (reader.ReadState != System.Xml.ReadState.EndOfFile)
        {
            string xmlText = reader.ReadOuterXml();
            ReportXML.Text += xmlText;
        }
}
```

Here's my markup code

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <pre>
                <asp:Literal ID="ReportXML" runat="server" />
            </pre>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

When I assign `ReportXML.Text = "blah"` it shows up fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the page to display the actual XML to the user, then you need to HTML-encode the value:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ReportXML" runat="server" Mode="Encode" />
```

Otherwise, the browser will treat the XML as HTML.

Comment: Thank you, it's all coming in 1 line though, is there a way to have it displayed formatted?

Comment: To format the XML document, you can use `ReportXML.Text +=
XDocument.Parse(xmlText).ToString();`.

Comment: Thank you, this works as well, by adding all the proper indention. Is there a way to also have the browser detect it is an xml page or to show the proper highlighting (just as if we opened a .xml document?)

Comment: Try Googling for a JavaScript-based XML code formatter / pretty printer.

Answer (score 1):

A Literal is exactly that, it will output your Xml verbatim.  What I suspect is happening is that this is now being interpreted within the Html and you can't see it (but you probably would if you viewed the source).  Therefore you need to encode it, as Michael Lieu suggests as I am typing this!